# would the variable 'x' in this piece of code be stores in stack memory, heap memory, or both?

Tags: java, heap-memory, activation-record

So regarding the variable `int x`. At the beginning of this class, `int x` and and `String s` are stored in heap memory. However, when the constructor is initiated, is `int x` stored in stack memory *AND* heap memory since the constructor is technically a method or not?

```
public class A {
    int x;
    public String s = "";

    public A(int y) {
        x = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: A constructor is not a method, and even if it was, that would not affect where the instance variable `x` is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y` is stored on the stack as it is a scoped variable to that method. `x` is just modified in-place on the heap.

Comment: so x=y doesn't store x in the stack at all then despite being in the method?

Comment: CosmicCat, the value is copied from y (on the stack) to x (on the heap).

Comment: The stack is built up from variables _defined_ in the method, not _all_ variables accessed in the method.